# Missing UI Elements in XCode 6

Tags: storyboard, xcode6, autolayout

I had this problem wherein my UI Elements seem to be missing/hidden in storyboard where in fact it is not.
This is a screenshot of my problem.

[image]

Comment: tell me one thing....what layout you use in storyboard like `W-any H-any` or what?

Comment: I figured out the problem from your question/answer. Thank you! It was originally wAny hRegular but out of no reason it became wAny hAny

Comment: yes...that what i want to tell you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is with your device layout....
Actually it makes on other layout like `wAny hAny` and now you show it on other layouts like `wCompact hRegular`....thats why the problem occurs...

Here is the visual presentation

[image]

You can enable it by checking the option installed for your size classes in your attribute inspector. Refer this image

[image]