# UIViewController content not displaying on storybord

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, uistoryboard

All the content of one of my UIViewControllers suddenly stop show in my storyboard, all the objects are grey out in my documents outline and the view controller in question is completely blank, however when I run the code it displays fine in my phone and/or simulator.

I try clean and build the project without any success, any ideas how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: check out here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your interface builder check the property for specific hidden view as Installed (From Utilities)

[image]

Comment: Thanks I was going crazy trying to figure out this!

Comment: @IcaroNZ I had same problem before and after 2 hours I got the result. :)

Comment: SO made me wait  2 minutes until I was able to accept, done now ;)

Comment: At that time I was not found the answer on SO :) @IcaroNZ Keep it up :)