# Why I can't see all my UIView in the Xib files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I got one problem when I am using the xib files. I got the source code from the outsourcing firm, and I just look at the xib files, they have several UI items like buttons, labels,etc. But I can't see them in the IB, 
I checked the attribute of the UI item, but seems everything is fine. How can I see the UILayout?  Here's my xib files below:
[image]

Comment: That is because of the size classes. Remove size classes in this xib, or change the device layout

Comment: check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757

Comment: Your button, label and other controls are not installed. Select you control and go to Attribute Inspector and the bottom check installed button. Your control will show active.

Answer (score 0):

From your interface builder check the property for specific hidden view as Installed (From Utilities) .

[image]