# Why all the objects of the content view in storyboard is non-visible? How strange it is

Tags: ios

[image]

All the thing are disappear, but it can be dragged to IB..

Comment: create your design in AnyAny and then you can change it in others as compact and regular . but if you do something in regular it is not visible in Compact

Comment: check and understand  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because,the objects is set up in one size class and you view it in another

Check here

[image]

Also,you can check which size class it is installed here.

[image]