# Xcode Size Classes: Display elements in many Size Classes

Tags: ios8, xcode6, autolayout, size-classes

I need some help.

I was designing my UI. My mistake is: **Using Size Classes**, I added some UI elements (buttons, labels) when I was in **[Compact, Any]** mode, and now I want to improve my UI being in **[Any, Any]** mode. The thing is, the elements I added in **[Compat, Any]** mode are not being displayed in **[Any, Any]** mode. I know this is the expected behavior.

My questions is: How can I show in **[Any, Any]** mode the elements I added in **[Compact, Any]** ??

Comment: you can check the picture below after gif in this link....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the installed check box in the utilities pane for the UI Elements in the view.

So select the View Elements and then in the right utilities pane you should see a couple check box under the Attributes.

The top one that is currently unchecked is the Any, Any Class...

So on your Compact/Regular class, Selecting the UI Element and then checking the top check box.

Then switch to your Any, Any Class and it will be visible.

You will just have to adjust your constraints for each element.

Comment: Sure, I now about this, but, I wonder if is possible to do it for many elements at the same time... I already fixed it manually, but I spent so much time {T_T} .. !!

Comment: Yes in the Document Outline pane you should be able to hold shift and select multiple elements and then Check the check box in the Attributes Pane.