# Xcode 7 Beta 5 - All subviews missing from Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xcode7, xcode7-beta5

I've recently switched up to Xcode 7 Beta 5 and I've been trying to solve the UITableView issue that I know lots have experienced. One solution I found was to disable size classes, however, once I did that I wanted to roll back my solution to a commit I just performed before that.

After I discarded all the changes I was presented with my view controllers and none of their subviews visible in them. In the hierarchy to the left they are listed but are 'greyed out'. Can anyone help with solving this?

Screenshot for reference:
[image: Storyboard subviews are missing on UIViews]

It's worthwhile noting that when the app runs all of the ui elements are still present as expected - just in storyboard they are not displaying.

Comment: check this.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking it in different layout such as any width compact height.
Grey out generally means that your view are active on a particular layout. 
You can see the changes when you tap in the bottom wAny hAny and select different sizes...