# Xcode - Issues with storyboard not displaying custom table view cell fields

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Im new to swift and xcode. Im creating a table view with custom cells. It happens that when create a custom cells and save it, the next time I open Xcode the custom cell does not show anymore the UILabels I have. They seems to be disabled for some reason.Im using Xcode 6.4

As you can see in the picture, there is some UILabels and even an image but they seems like disabled and they dont show up on Xcode.

What is the issue?

[image]

Comment: this may help you....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757

Comment: El captain yes, it might be that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you have to select the size class. currently yours is set to any any. that is why they are grayed out.
hope this helps.