# View hides in hierarchy when using autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I have view in storyboard which using auto layout and something weird is happening when I want to select those UI elements (marked with red arrow) from Class root hierarchy those are hidden there. I am attaching screen shots below.

[image]

View in storyboard

[image]

Comment: check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757

Answer (score 1):

Click the hidden view. Go to Attributes Inspector and check the Installed checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Those views are invisible because you included those views when your view controller had some other size as in `size class`.
When you view your VC in some other size than it was before, those previous views would be rendered invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer so I am posting screen shot which options as marked with red arrow.

[image]