# UI items do not show up in interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I have a strange issue here about interface builder.
I added some views, buttons to my view controller and they were displayed well in the interface builder some hours before. But now, they disappeared.
I mean, they are not displayed in the interface builder while showing up perfectly when running. Below images is the view controller in my interface builder.
[image: Nothing is showing up in the view controller]

[image: And the view hierarchy .Items are grey outed]

Here is some other view controller in the same project. Items in it are showing normally.
[image: Items are showing]

[image: Items in view hierarchy. Not grey outed.]

Could anyone tell me the reason of this ?

**EDIT:** They disappeared after I installed some libraries using cocoapods. Can it be the reason?

Comment: Are you using size classes? I have seen this issue when the subviews are dragged on to the view in one size class, and then they don't get shown properly in another size class.

Comment: check this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the size class，you may add views in one size class and see it in another
[image]

Also,selected the hidden view to check if it is installed in this size class
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Worked.