# Setting constraints in different size classes, view does not appear in landscape

Tags: ios, interface-builder, size-classes

I am trying to get my head around the size classes.

I have my constraints set for compact width and any height (iPhone portrait):

[image]

This works as expected (I want the box at the top of the screen) i.e.:

[image]

Now I am trying to set the constraints for this square for the landscape orientation. I want the yellow square to stick to the left hand side of the screen in landscape. I select any wAny and hCompact in the interface builder but my yellow block isn't there to edit the constraints for:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I'm a little confused about what happens. Do I need to add another new yellow block or am I adjusting the constraints of the existing one? Any pointers would be much appreciated! thanks

Comment: use installed property for size class....check this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757

Comment: Okay, just done that. The constraints aren't greyed out now. But I am in wAny and hCompact on the interface builder and I still can't see the yellow square, not sure how I edit the constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use size classes

- First select wAny hAny (This will be active on all sizes)

Add the following constraints:

- Top Space to : Superview
- Trailing Space to : Superview
- Leading Space to : Superview
- Height Equals : 220

The result on iPhone

[image]

Now add customization in any class you want. In this case we are adding customization to wAny hCompact

The Constraints on this will be:

- Here two constraints (height constraint and Trailing constraint) are uninstalled for wAny hCompact as Shown in picture

[image]

[image]

Now additional constraints on this are

- Bottom space to Superview
- Width Equals : 220

The result on lanscape is as given:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your view will be disabled for wAny hCompact. Select the view from  view controller scene from left pane and drag and drop to wAny hCompact view. Then set constraints.