# Buttons are displayed as disabled on UIViewController in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, adaptive-layout

I have developed my app using storyboards with `size:iPhone3.5inch` in simulated metrics..My app is working fine where after designing nearly 10 screens of my app, my storyboard showing some weried behaviour (Described below With image)..

In my menu page I have 9 buttons

[image]

Storyboard scene details (**button icons are showing as disabled and related view controller is showing blank**) with frame values. If I select any button ,It shows the frames common for all the 9 buttons as shown below frame details

[image]

Is this behaviour is normal or should I make any changes..This is my first storyboard app .(Used only XIB's till now)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: may be sizeclass is a problem....use installed property

Comment: Is this is a normal behaviour or should I delete and recreate my storyboard to enable buttons (App is working fine in all the device versions)?

Comment: check this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757

Comment: @EI Captain thank you..I will check it...