# xCode Storyboard behavior invisible fields

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I've a strange issue with my storyboard. 
I added a field in a storyboard, and since that, all my project have the same issue.
I only can see the fields that I've not to scroll to see them. All other fields are invisible. When I build the project, everything is normal, but I can't edit my storyboard if I see nothing x)

Is there anyone who had the same issue?

Thanks for reading/helping me :)

[image: The top of a random scene. Everything seems normal.]

[image: And if I scroll down, here's what I've got]

Comment: Yeah I had a similar issue. When I zoom out that happens but then I zoom in and click around/click and drag my mouse across the screen and they appear again. Did you try restarting Xcode?

Comment: EICaptain No, they look normal in the left bar.
rinyfo4 I restarted xCode, my Mac, everything I could :(

Comment: Can you update your question and post a picture of your storyboard? I think that would help. The other comment above mine was deleted, not sure where it went but the link the user posted was great. Did you check it out? It was this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757 you're not experiencing this problem?

Comment: I read that before the post was deleted but it wasn't helpful. But Thanks for posting it :)
(I added images)

Comment: Select your view controller, in the right panel, fifth tab with a rule icon, change `Simulated size` to `Freeform` then increase height of view controller.

Comment: I'll try it but i doubt it will work. The issue now happens in all my project. I think I broke xCode x) I'm downloading it again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not having a perfect answer, but: If your UI elements in the storyboard are not visible, you should be able to access them using the "Document Outline". You can activate that in the menu "Editor > Show Document Outline" or by clicking on the little "sidebar" icon in the bottom left corner of the storyboard view:

[image]

Then you will see the elements on the left and you can click on them:

[image]

For instance, if one sets some fields hidden, it is easier to find them in the document outline.

Comment: I always have this bar opened, very useful to use the constraints properly ;)
But I can't work only with this bar and not seeing my scenes.