# Button disappeared from the main view controller, and those buttons are greyed out in the "controller scene", how to get it back

Tags: ios, swift

I'm attempting the beginner's project of building a calculator in Swift. I'm up to the stage where I have already added basic operators into the calculator's main view controller.

However, I'm not sure what I have done, but the basic operator buttons suddenly all disappeared from the main view controller and I can't seem to get it back. When I looked at the controller scene, the basic operator buttons are all grey out. How do I get it back?

[image]

Comment: Check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757

Comment: Add a size class for Any-Any on the element to make it "re-appear". You usually want to add all elements in that particular Any-Any class and then define **constraints** for specific size classes (Any-Compact and stuff like that). That technique also prevents elements from re-allocate when changing size classes (rotating the device). If you have two elements on two different size classes, they will be different instances when rotating on device, but a single elements on Any-Any with constraints for diferent size classes will simply relocate on the layout.