# My UI elements are missing

Tags: ios, xcode

What happend to my elements? Suddenly it dissapeared. All I can see is the blurred type of the elements that I used.

[image]

Comment: Check Autolyout,it may be made for some other layout just go on Any width and Any Height in storyboard and check for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing UI Elements in XCode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you set them `hidden`

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your layout it might not be enabled. Click one of the gray elements, then look on the right side for a box that is unchecked for that specific layout. When you change the layout from say All layouts, to a specific layout, such as just iPhone, the elements aren't set for that layout, so you need to specify. It will be on the right side with an unchecked box. Sorry this isn't more clear, I am not near XCode currently and forget the names :P

Answer (score 0):

Verify if your view is installed. 
Select your view, go to attributes inspector and check the "Installed" checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Two possible cases can be included here:

**1. The View is hidden.**

**Solution:** Select the view. And, in the Attribute's Inspector on the right, uncheck the `hidden` property.

**2. You are using size classes. And, You uninstalled the view for the size current size class.**

**Note:** Check if the storyboard has a blue highlight at the bottom of the screen.

**Solution:** Select the view. And, select the Attribute inspector's fifth tab. It lists all the constraints and size class information. Check if it has something named `installed` written.

Then, check the installed checkbox to make the view installed.