# Storyboard elements invisible

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I don't know what button I pressed wrong in Xcode, but all elements become invisible in storyboard, preview and simulator. here is the screenshot:
[image]

It is certainly some wrong button press/click that caused this problem.

Please help!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableViews.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your view hierarchy, it looks like you may have placed the background image `chalkboard` above the rest of your UI elements. If you move `chalkboard` to be the first item under `View`, you should then see the content of all other views, rather than just their outline.