# ios Xcode storyboard compact not working

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm draw story board. but compact changed not showing storyboard.

i want to base value showing storyboard.

compact final value( tableview ) -> compact base value ( blank show view ) changed. after not showing.

how do i complete problem?

[image]

[image]

1. compact base value - > not storyboard ( blank )
2. compact final value - > show tableview !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757  .. use install property of sizeclass and give constraints

Comment: make sure that your control (tableview or whatever) is installed for that size class. You can check that from `attribute inspector`